# Unable to click ImageButton

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have a following layout in `main_view.xml` which contains a `ImageButton` in it, button when i click/touch the button the `ButtonListener` function never gets called.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapArea"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</fragment>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/findingLocation"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightLeftMargin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/rightLeftMargin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button1text"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_feed_active" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightLeftMargin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_button2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/rightLeftMargin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightLeftMargin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button3View"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_active" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And following code in MainActivity.Java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    User usrObj = new User();
    if (usrObj.authenticateUser())
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
    else
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
}

public void ButtonListener() {

    ImageButton oggleButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);

    ToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ImageButton is clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

}
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to call `ButtonListener` method when  `usrObj.authenticateUser()` is true. do it as:

```
if (usrObj.authenticateUser())
   {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
        ButtonListener ();  << call here
   }
    else
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
```

and also attach `setOnClickListener` to `oggleButton` instead of `ToggleButton`

Answer (score 0):

apart from above suggestions from ρяσѕρєя K, here is one more thing you have to take care is.

instead of this below code.

```
oggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

use this one

```
oggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // use View.oncli......
```